# Problems reading binary file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read the first 6 bytes of a file, but it's giving me weird results, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
struct Block {
    char fileSize[3];
    char initialDataBlockId[3];
};

int main(int c, char **a) {

    ifstream file("C\\main_file_cache.idx0", ios::binary);

    Block block;

    file.get((char*)&block, sizeof(block));

    printf("File Size: %i\n", block.fileSize);
    printf("Initial Data Block ID: %i\n", block.initialDataBlockId);

    file.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Before I ran the code, I opened the file in a binary editor,
and it showed me this hex code:

```
    00 00 00 00-00 00 05 af-4b 00 00 01-26 df cd 00
    00 6f 03 3f-ed 00 03 61-05 08 35 00-04 8b 01 61
    59 00 08 39-03 23 0a 00-05 6c 00 35-d0 00 06 fe
    03 69 d8 00-07 19
```

There are a total of 54 bytes. The first 6 bytes are just zero.

So, I expected my program to produce the following output:

```
File Size: 0
Initial Data Block ID: 0
```

Instead, the outputs is as follows:

```
File Size: 10419128
Initial Data Block ID: 10419131
```

This result makes no sense. Maybe there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: what are these dashes in the file?

Comment: @EugeneSh. They seem to separate each 4 columns.

Comment: You are printing the addresses of the arrays.

Comment: also, sizeof(...) does not work with structs the way you think it does.

Comment: Use `ifstream::read()` instead of `ifstream::get()`. The latter is intended for c-strings. `read()` is for any data.

Comment: C++ is not C.  It is possible to write code that compiles and has the same semantics in both languages, but yours is not such code.

Comment: Jack up your compiler warning level. Some modern compilers look at the `printf` format string and can tell you if you are providing it the wrong datatypes.

Comment: Perhaps read this for a refresher on C++ binary file reading: http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use type `unsigned char` in your `Block` structure.

You should use `file.read()` to read binary data instead of `file.get()`.

You are printing the addresses of the arrays in the `Block` structure, not their contents, furthermore the specifier `%i` expects an `int`, not a `char *`, so the behavior in undefined and you get some weird integer value but anything culd have happened, including program termination. Increasing the warning level is advisable so the compiler warns about such silly mistakes.

If the file format is little endian, you could convert these 3 byte arrays to numbers this way:

```
int block_fileSize =  (unsigned char)block.fileSize[0] + 
                     ((unsigned char)block.fileSize[1] << 8) + 
                     ((unsigned char)block.fileSize[2] << 16);
int block_initialDataBlockId =  (unsigned char)block.initialDataBlockId[0] +
                               ((unsigned char)block.initialDataBlockId[1] << 8) +
                               ((unsigned char)block.initialDataBlockId[2] << 16);
printf("File Size: %i\n", block_fileSize);
printf("Initial Data Block ID: %i\n", block_initialDataBlockId);
```

Comment: Why does `printf("%i", array)` print the address of the array instead of the contents?

Comment: @zett42 `"%i"` is for printing an `int`, not a `char [3]`, nor the address of the array.  Since code used a mis-matched specifier and argument, the result is undefined behavior and in your case, it appeared like the address of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a binary data you can use a `read` method from `ifstream` and also `write` method from `ofstream`.

```
istream & ifstream::read (char * s, streamsize n);
ostream & ofstream::write (const char * s, streamsize n);
```

You have to know that binary mode is useless for UNIX systems and text mode is only useful.